# Visual C++ project runs fine through VStudio but from Explorer dies after appearing in Notify Tray

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, streamreader, visual-c++-2008-express

I just modified my C++/CLI project to change the way it was parsing its config.ini text file. But it still accesses the file on the disk just as before:

```cpp
StreamReader ^sr = gcnew StreamReader(CONFFILE_NAME);
String ^rdfl = sr->ReadToEnd();
sr->Close();
```

Now it won't run outside of the VS2008Express environment. It is a WinForm pretending to be a service and should stay in the notification tray but instead it just flashes its default icon there until I roll my mouse over it, a sure sign it has already terminated abnormally. The default icon should immediately be updated btw so I will check upto that point again. I've just tried a clean and rebuild.

Thanks.

_***EDIT*_**

It runs fine if the config file is not there or is incompatible - a window appears and I enter the correct config and off she goes. But it reloads config data from a file from within VS2008 and it used to from without (albeit with a major logical error in the coding).

Here's the code immediately following that posted above:

```cpp
    int fore = 0;
    int aft;
    while (statsRead < 4) {
        fore = rdfl->IndexOf(':', aft)+1;
        if (fore == -1) break;
        aft = rdfl->IndexOf('\n', fore);
        if (aft == -1) break;
        if (statsRead == 0) str1 = rdfl->Substring(fore, aft-fore)->Trim();
        else if (statsRead == 1) str2 = rdfl->Substring(fore, aft-fore)->Trim();
        else {
            String ^tmpIntStr = rdfl->Substring(fore, aft-fore)->Trim();
            int tmp_int;
            if (Int32::TryParse(tmpIntStr, tmp_int)) {
                switch (statsRead) {
                    case 2: int1 = tmp_int; break;
                    case 3: int2 = tmp_int; break;
                }
            } else break;
        }
        ++statsRead;
    }
}
```

afterwards any remaining stats are given default values which work in my case, apart from the first which triggers the window.

_***EDIT*_**

I've updated the above with try and catch blocks as advocated by Hans and also the MSDN literatur for StreamReader but still it fails, the stack trace (thanks, Hans) indicates the fault is my `while` statement (no thanks, MS)

```cpp
if (File::Exists(CONFFILE_NAME)) {
    String ^rdfl;
    try {
        StreamReader ^sr = gcnew StreamReader(CONFFILE_NAME);
        try{
            rdfl = sr->ReadToEnd();
        } finally {
            if ( sr )
                delete (IDisposable^)sr;
        }
    } catch (Exception ^ex) {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
    }
    int fore = 0;
    int aft;
    while (statsRead < 4) {
        fore = rdfl->IndexOf(':', aft)+1;
        if (fore == -1) break;
        aft = rdfl->IndexOf('\n', fore);
        if (aft == -1) break;
        if (statsRead == 0) str1 = rdfl->Substring(fore, aft-fore)->Trim();
        else if (statsRead == 1) str2 = rdfl->Substring(fore, aft-fore)->Trim();
        else {
            String ^tmpIntStr = rdfl->Substring(fore, aft-fore)->Trim();
            int tmp_int;
            if (Int32::TryParse(tmpIntStr, tmp_int)) {
                switch (statsRead) {
                    case 2: int1 = tmp_int; break;
                    case 3: int2 = tmp_int; break;
                }
            } else break;
        }
        ++statsRead;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running VS with elevated permissions? (ie: as admin)

Comment: Elevated for lowly old me, lol. My default Windows account is of type "Computer Administrator"

Comment: int fore = 0;
int aft;
should be
int aft = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically a simple mistake, like CONFFILE_NAME not being a full path name and the default working directory not set where you hope it is.  Focus on getting a debugger attached.  That's easy in .NET, use System::Diagnostics::Debugger::Launch() in your Main() method for example.  And write an event handler for AppDomain::CurrentDomain->UnhandledException so that exceptions don't fall in the bit bucket without notice.  Be sure to remove try/catch statements that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Worked a charm, thanks already. But still confused why the error is only apparent outside of the VS launcher.

Comment: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: startIndex" That isn't one of my variables!?

Comment: Sure it is, your variable referencing a .NET class.  Don't forget to also display the exception's StackTrace property so you can see how it went bad.  Simple in the event handler with e->UnhandledException->ToString().  And use the debugger.

Comment: If I wrap all the code given above in try {/*..*/} catch (Exception ^ex) {MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);}
It just works, no MessageBox or anything, if I don't it doesn't. Why is this? Re: last comment, but the debugger wasn't finding the fault, I will try again though.

Comment: You are asking me to reverse-engineer buggy code from a 'this doesn't work' comment.  I don't know how to do that.  You are ignoring my advice to automatically attach a debugger, use AppDomain::UnhandledException and e->UnhandledException->ToString().  Not sure why, good luck with it!

Comment: looking at the stack trace, below the prev. msg. is "  at System.String.IndexOf(Char value, Int32 StartIndex, Int32 Count)\n  at ..my ctor\n  MyClass.cpp:line 21" paraphrased, which is the third line show above, "sr->Close();". Sorry for asking the impossible, I was just trying to keep your attention while I got coding. I would guess I shouldn't be closing the file after reading it all in, don't think that was in the MSDN literature. I'll attach dbg'r.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is an error in my translation of C# code, to C++, seems I need to reimplement the using(..) bit.